# Need the regex for this string in python?

Tags: python, regex

I written regex for the particular string as mentioned below. match group(1) is including the values. I would need only the string portion rather than values.

```
import re

line = "dev_interface_values, 123 23, 8 1"
line2= "my_port_values2, 1234, 81"
m = re.search(r'^\s*(.+), (.*\S)\s*$', line)

print  m.group(1)
print  m.group(2)

m1 = re.search(r'^\s*(.+), (.*\S)\s*$', line2)

print  m1.group(1)
print  m1.group(2)
```

Output:

```
dev_interface_values, 123 23
8 1
my_port_values2, 1234
81
```

Expecting Output as :

```
m.group(1) -> dev_interface_values
m.group(2) -> 123 23, 8 1

m.group(1) -> my_port_values2
m.group(2) -> 1234, 81
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make first capture group lazy by using `?`:

```
import re
line = "dev_interface_values, 123 23, 8 1"
line2 = "my_port_values2, 1234, 81"
for i in [line,line2]:
    m = re.fullmatch(r'^\s*(.+?), (.*\S)\s*$', i)
    print(m.group(1))
    print(m.group(2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex ([see it in action here](https://regex101.com/r/ghrvzs/1)):

```
^(\w+)\,\s*(.*\S)$
```

String 1 output:

```
dev_interface_values
123 23, 8 1
```

String 2 output:

```
my_port_values2
1234, 81
```

Comment: To the downvoter, could you kindly elaborate in what way my answer could be improved?

Comment: The above answer is working fine. Thanks a lot. But i don't understood why it is down voted. Any best answers are appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, @john517501! I'm not sure what the issue is either - hopefully it can be elaborated upon by the downvoter.